# How to find optical flow only inside bounding box?

Tags: python, opencv, feature-detection, opticalflow

I'm using the Lucas-Kanade sparse optical flow method where I'm finding feature points using the Shi-Tomasi corner detector [Good Features to Track](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d4/d8c/tutorial_py_shi_tomasi.html).

How do I detect feature points only inside the bounding box?

Answer (score 0):

How about cropping the BB from the image, and running the Shi-Tomasi on the cropped image, then adding the offset of the BB (upper left corner coords) to the key-points.